# Automatically convert spherical jpeg image (360x360 view) into a movie sequence for youtube

Tags: youtube, photo, panoramas, oculus, virtual-reality

Is there any way/program(s)/api/etc. which can help to write a program which can automatically convert a spherical jpeg image (for example like http://www.jcwilson.net/craigendarroch.jpg) into a virtual reality movie so that youtube can enable the view-around function?

The photo should just be displayed for maybe 10 seconds.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're looking for a way to change a picture to a movie with one frame that lasts 10 seconds? You want ffmpeg for that: [Create a video slideshow from images](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images)
.

The question is: why on youtube? There are better ways to display a spherical picture.

Oh and it's 360x180.

Comment: Thank you very much for this link! I know other ways (like krpano which I have or so). In my specific situation I should do it with YouTube.